# How to separate an <a> element which is inside a <p> element

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text <a href="/es/cunit"
class="more-link">more</a></p>
```

So, the "more" link is shown inline with the "some text.." text.

I need it to be place in a new line just below the text.

`display: block;` doesn't work because it will fill the 100% of the width.

The html code is generated by a CSM, then I don't want to change it.

Picture below:
[image]
I can't upload a picture with Safari ...:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :before :after pseudo element and placing content: "\A" which denotes to line feed character:

```css
p a:after, p a:before { content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }
```

```html
<p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text <a href="/es/cunit"
class="more-link">more</a></p>
```

Comment: `\A`? What does that mean?

Comment: Almost there, I have some problem with 'display:inline-block,' which is inherited from other style. Can you please add the right value for 'display' to override mine. Thanks.

Comment: @JPashs um, what? you don't need it.

Comment: I know but it is inherited from other style. Can tell me which is the right one to override it? The style 'display:inline-block' is attached to the '<a>' element

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sufficient reputation to comment, so I'm posting it here. But why don't you user a line break tag.

```
<br>
```

Make your code like this.

```
<p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
<br> 
<a href="/es/cunit"
class="more-link">more</a></p>
```

Comment: The html code is generated by a CSM, then I don't want to change it.

Comment: I'm not sure why I got down voted. Can some one explain if I did something wrong? I'm new here.

Comment: Okay, two reasons. 1. Your answer does not help. 2. Your answer should actually been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
.more-link:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```